# Microsoft Document Explorer Displays Error

Tags: document, explorer

Microsoft Document Explorer is displaying the following error message on several pages "This webpage might not be displayed properly. The content of the webpage does not match the type specified by the server.". It has been doing this ever since I installed Visual Studio Express for Web 2012. How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Installing the update for Visual Studio 2012 fixed this problem.